# how to get the domain name with router in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the domain with the `Router` through `ActivatedRouter` but I can't get the domain.

Is there a way to get the domain name from one of them?

Comment: in the `OnInit` cycle: `console.log(window.location.href);` or even better: `window.location.origin`

Comment: @Gal please check my updated answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get full `Location` object using the code, where you can find everything related to the router including hostname, URL, params etc -

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
   console.log(document.location);
}
```

The object contains info -

```
{
  "href": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "ancestorOrigins": {},
  "origin": "http://localhost:4200",
  "protocol": "http:",
  "host": "localhost:4200",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "port": "4200",
  "pathname": "/",
  "search": "",
  "hash": ""
}
```

## Alternate -

```
window.location.href
```

Also, `router` object from angular contains much information about router/navigation.

Comment: you have to keep in mind that Document and window will not work together with server side Rendering

Comment: may I know where in question mentioned about usage of SSR? Also if OP wants to use he can just after adding some checks of platformBrowser for SSR to work. Hope I clearly understand your concern

Answer (score 1):

**Give try on this below code**

*Create a Variable of Location Type*

```
public location: Location
this.location['_platformStrategy']._platformLocation.location.host
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Document` object instead of this complex string, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use plain javascript
create a variable and use below code

"window.location.hostname"